# SharePoint/ASP.NET life cycle and databinding

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, data-binding

I'm having a issue with databinding to a grid and what event to do it in. I'm using the DevExpress ASPxGridView, but it also happens with a few other grids I've tried.

We rely on a web part property to determine what data to retrieve, so we have to do the grid databinding in the OnPreRender event. If we do any grouping, then the expand/collapse of the grid doesn't work. If the databinding is moved to the OnLoad event then everything works fine. Is there a proper way to do this or is it just not supported?

Thanks

Comment: Here is a great explanation of when to use which events for a sharepoint web part. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/ca47c7a9-226d-412d-8390-041edc154636/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great explanation of when to use which events for a sharepoint web part. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/ca47c7a9-226d-412d-8390-041edc154636/

That being said, I generally stick to the createchildcontrols events.

Comment: I do know about the events and generally when each is called. It's just I thought, depending on a web part property, what data should be gotten would be a pretty common scenario. So I thought I must be missing something obvious, but it doesn't seem like it.